# Animate moving of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview

I'm using a `UICollectionView` with flow layout in my app. My data source is an array of objects, which are sorted in certain order. Each cell in the collection view represents an object in the array. I update the collection view every time an object is removed from/added to the array or when the order of existing objects in the array changes.

I'm able to animate appearing and disappearing of the cells using `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` and `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:`. However, I wasn't able to find a similar nice looking solution on how to animate changing the order of the cells.

If I wasn't clear, here's an example - let's say I have 8 cells and 8 objects in the corresponding array. Object at index 6 then moves to index 4, therefore object at index 4 moves to index 5 and object at index 5 moves to index 6. The cells now have to move to new positions, as well. Does anyone know how to animate the switching of cells' positions?

Comment: Why don't you delete the item at the before index, then insert the same item  at the new index?

Comment: I think what you want is making cell moving to new position, right? Did you try moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: ?